# General set of integer solutions $(p,q)$ to $1 = pa + qb$ for integers $a,b$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $a,b,c$ are positive integers satisfying that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $c \geq (a-1)(b-1)$, I want to show there are non-negative integers $s,t$ such that $c = as + bt$.

As $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $c$ is an integer, I know that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $c$ so there exists integers $p,q$ satisfying that $c = ap + bq$. I am not quite sure of the significance of $c \geq (a-1)(b-1)$ which will allow these integers to be non-negative though.

I think my question about this really is, can the set of integer solutions $p,q$ to $c = ap + bq$ be further generalized in such a way that for an integer variable $r$, every set of solutions $(p,q)$ can be generalized as $(p=f(r),q=g(r))$? If anyone can point me in a direction or pass a hint, much appreciated.

Comment: @T.Bongers Generally the solution given with Euclid's algorithm for positive integers $a,b$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ with give integers $p,q$ such that $1 = pa + qb$, but one of $p,q$ will be positive and the other negative. For the solution of $c = sa+tb$, I need both $s,t$ to be positive.

Comment: For $c \geqslant (a-1)(b-1)$, let $c \equiv r \pmod{a}$. With $1 = pa + qb$, let $t$ be the smallest nonnegative remainder of $rq$ modulo $a$. Then $c - tb \equiv 0 \pmod{a}$, and $c - tb \geqslant c - (a-1)b \geqslant (a-1)(b-1) - (a-1)b = -(a-1) > -a$, hence $c - tb \geqslant 0$, therefore there are nonnegative integers $s$ and $t$ with $c = sa + tb$. In any representation $(a-1)(b-1) - 1 = ab - a - b = sa + tb$, one of $s$ and $t$ must be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By Bezout's Theorem, since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$, and therefore integers $s$ and $t$ such that $c=as+bt$ (just multiply through by $c$). But you know about this. Now we deal with the problem of making $s$ and $t$ non-negative. That certainly cannot always be done, but if $c$ is large enough it can be.

Note that for any integer $k$, we have 
$$a(s+kb)+b(t-ka)=c.$$ 
Show that if $c$ is large enough, we can choose $k$ so that $s+kb$ and $t-ka$ are both non-negative. As a further hint, choose $k$ so that $s+kb$ is as small non-negative as possible, so between $0$ and $b-1$.  Show that if $c\ge (a-1)(b-1)$ then $t-ka$ is also non-negative.