# Show that this set of integers can be expressed in the form $7r+10s$ with $r, s$ non-negative integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The set of integers are: ${54,55,...,60}$

I am having trouble with the non-negative integers part, otherwise the question appears to be quite simple.

I have that since $gcd(7,10) = 1$, by extended euclidean algorithm, I can easily find r,s such that $7r+10s = 1$

So I can easily multiply by the respective element of the set to find $r,s$ in each case. But one of $r,s$ must be negative.

I know this question is similar to:

[General set of integer solutions $(p,q)$ to $1 = pa + qb$ for integers $a,b$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465541/general-set-of-integer-solutions-p-q-to-1-pa-qb-for-integers-a-b-suc)

But I have reviewed and don't completely follow the accepted answer. Could someone elaborate a little further for me, or give me a hint to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest way is simply to express each of these $7$ numbers in the desired form. For instance, $54=40+14=2\cdot7+4\cdot10$, and $55=35+20=5\cdot7+2\cdot10$. There’s no need to invoke theory here. If your goal is to prove that **all** integers $\ge54$ can be so represented, this is an easy induction once you establish that these $7$ can be.

Comment: Yeah, checking that each number 54-60 can be represented in the desired way is the base-case of your induction, and I think that the only really reasonable way to do it is to noodle out each one by just seeing how many 10's you have to subtract to get a multiple of 7.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: It’s not the *only* way, but it is the most elementary. One can also quote Sylvester’s result whose proof is sketched in the answer at the link; that’s essentially what vadim123 has done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the answer that you linked to, we have that

$3\cdot 7 +(- 2)\cdot 10 =1$.

Now, we multiply this by, say, 54, so now we have

$162\cdot 7 +(- 108)\cdot 10 =54$.

Now we add a zero:

$162\cdot 7 +(- 108)\cdot 10 + k\cdot 10\cdot 7-k\cdot 10 \cdot 7=54$,

with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Remember that we want a linear combination with non negative coefficients, so we factor the equation like this:

$(162-k\cdot 10)\cdot 7 +(- 108+k\cdot 7)\cdot 10 =54$.

Taking $k=16$, we have that

$2\cdot 7 +4\cdot 10 =54$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The [Frobenius number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_number#n_.3D_2) of 7 and 10 is $$g(7,10)=7\cdot 10-7-10=53$$
Hence every integer greater than or equal to 54 may be expressed as a nonnegative linear combination of 7 and 10.